# How to edit CGI script website files as a user?

Tags: php, security, web, cgi

This is just a hypothetical question. Let's say we have a website built using CGI scripts. I find a folder within it (for ex; www.website.com/links/link.txt) and it has some basic text files. When I enter this URL on a browser, I am able to see the file "link.txt". I also know that the website is running on Apache Tomcat.

My question is, how do I (as a user) edit this link.txt file? What tools should I use?

Comment: It's probably a good question, but not really about programming ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a web-based editor you can't edit the files directly; this is for security purposes as if you can change the file that means anyone else can too.

You will need a way to either connect to the server and edit it using a remote session, or you will need to edit the file using your computer and then upload it. Unfortunately you have already mentioned that ssh and ftp aren't working, which are the two ways I would have otherwise suggested.

I would suggest you get in touch with your site host and ask them what functionality they provide to allow you to edit files.

Hope this helps!